# Cannot union two Joints Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, union

Im trying to union 2 joins, but im getting weird error...

I have "Clientes" -> means clients, and i got all the clients that they got registered in orders and news.

In news table i got the cliente_id -> client_id ,
And in orders, i got the same, cliente_id -> client_id,

In news i got x clients, and in orders i got Y clients, they are 99% diferent usually,

I want to get all those clients in orders and in news.

So i did a MYSQL query that it works...

```
SELECT c.nombre, c.apellidos, c.id ,p.id FROM pedidos p
join clientes c on c.id = p.cliente_id
UNION
SELECT c.nombre, c.apellidos, c.id, n.id FROM noticias n
join clientes c on c.id = n.cliente_id
```

The problem is that in LAralvel o query builder it doesnt not work.

```
 $firstSQL = Pedido::select('clientes.nombre','clientes.apellidos','clientes.id', 'pedidos.id')
        ->join('clientes', 'clientes.id', '=', 'pedidos.cliente_id')
        ->get();

 $total = Noticia::select('clientes.nombre','clientes.apellidos','clientes.id', 'noticias.id')
        ->join('clientes', 'clientes.id', '=', 'noticias.cliente_id')
        ->union($firstSQL)
        ->get();
```

I got this error... **BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getBindings does not exist.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `get()` from first query

```
 $firstSQL = Pedido::select('clientes.nombre','clientes.apellidos','clientes.id', 'pedidos.id')
        ->join('clientes', 'clientes.id', '=', 'pedidos.cliente_id');

 $total = Noticia::select('clientes.nombre','clientes.apellidos','clientes.id', 'noticias.id')
        ->join('clientes', 'clientes.id', '=', 'noticias.cliente_id')
        ->union($firstSQL)
        ->get();
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions